# Youtube API, nexturl and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, youtube-api

I've managed to upload a video to YouTube via CORS and XMLHttpRequest so that I can provide a progress bar on the uploads. However after the upload gets to 100% and the video appears in the YouTube channel, the error handler is called.

I think this is to do with the nextUrl parameter which has to be provided as part of the form action. Has anyone come across this and does anyone have a workaround?

I've seen this ([Can I upload to youtube without a full page refresh using FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340903/can-i-upload-to-youtube-without-a-full-page-refresh-using-formdata)) on StackOverflow but it doesn't help as I don't want to host the videos on our servers.

Cheers
Simon

Comment: I've noticed that the callback works if 2 criteria are met - 1) Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is added to the nextUrl response, 2) you don't attach to xhr.upload progress event.  Personally I'm not happy with this as a solution, but I can't figure out any way to do it with progress enabled.

Comment: What I ended up doing instead was adding a unique id to the tags of the video being uploaded, then on the error event which occurs at the end of uploading I polled youtube services to get the latest videos for the current user, found the video with the correct tag and grabbed the ID/status from there.

Comment: Thanks for that - sounds like a plan. I'll give it a shot.